# change sku for all products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import, sku

I import more than 2000 products in magento but I have a problem, I don't know what is the reason but now at the end of each sku appear `_1` is there any way to remove this for all skus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be just to run this sql query on your database.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity
SET sku = CONCAT(LEFT(sku, CHAR_LENGTH(sku) -2), '')
WHERE sku LIKE '%_1';
```

You can add a `where` condition if you need it for a certain group of products.

Backup first.

Comment: thank you so much, but now I observe there only some sku's have _1 this value, not all, is there any way to idetify this value and replace it?

Comment: I added a where condition to filter out only the ones that end with `_1`.

Comment: catalog_entity_product in not exist, I change with catalog_product_entity, but now I have this #1054 - Unknown column '%_1' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry for that. I wrote the answer in a hurry. I changed the table name and some quotes. Try it again.

Comment: is perfect, my problem was solved, thank you so much for your help